# TypeError: this.edad.reduce is not a function

Tags: javascript

Intenté hacerlo con ayuda de un vídeo, pero no me sale; si me pueden ayudar les agradecería. getPromedioEdad() {

```
function crearClasePersona() {
 class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
   this.nombre= nombre;
   this.edad= edad;
   this.hobbies= hobbies;
   this.amigos= amigos;
}
```

El método 'getPromedioEdad' debe retornar el promedio de edad de los amigos de una persona

```
  Ej:// Si la persona tuviera estos amigos:
  // {
  //   amigos: [{
  //     nombre: 'toni',
  //     edad: 33,
  //   }, {
  //     nombre: 'Emi',
  //     edad: 25
  //   }]
  // }
  // persona.getPromedioEdad() debería devolver 29 ya que (33 + 25) / 2 = 29

  // Tu código aca:

  var sum= this.edad.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
  var prom = sum / this.edad.length;{
    return prom;
  }
    }
  };
```

Me tira este error:

```
should get age average with getPromedioEdad (6ms)

 Clase › crearClasePersona › should get age average with getPromedioEdad

TypeError: this.edad.reduce is not a function

  172 |
  173 |       // Tu código aca:
> 174 |       var sum= this.edad.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
  175 |       var prom = sum / this.edad.length;{
  176 |         return prom;
  177 |       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola que tal puedes intentar lo siguiente

```js
var amigos = [
    {
        nombre: 'Toni',
        edad: 33,
    },
    {
        nombre: 'Emi',
        edad: 25,
    }
]

console.log(calcularEdadPromedio(amigos));

function calcularEdadPromedio(array) {
    let sumaTotal = 0;
    let edadPromedio;
    for (let amigo of array) {
        sumaTotal += amigo.edad;
    }
    edadPromedio = sumaTotal/array.length;
    return edadPromedio;
}
```

primero tenemos nuestro arreglo donde colocamos los amigos.

Después dentro de nuestra función `calcluarEdadPromedio` declaramos una variable donde iremos sumando las edades.
creamos un bucle `for` donde iteramos cada amigo y sumamos su edad a nuestra variable anterior.

Por ultimo realizamos la operación donde dividimos la suma total de las edades sobre el tamaño del arreglo y retornamos el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ahi muestras o me parece es un array de objetos, al cual:

- Lo iteras con reduce
- A la variable que nos recupera los valores en cada iteracion le indicas que acceda a la clave edad
- Ahí mismo divides entre dos

Código

```
const amigos = [
{
  name: 23,
  edad: 56
},
{
  name: 23,
  edad: 46
}]

let data = amigos.reduce(valor => valor.edad + valor.edad / 2)
```

De está forma reduce podría acceder al valor numérico deseado  así te ahorras ciclos innecesarios

Comment: se sigue dando error, el método getPromedioEdad esta dentro de una clase Persona, que tiene estas propiedades
 this.nombre= nombre;
      this.edad= edad;
      this.hobbies= hobbies;
      this.amigos= amigos;

Comment: Disculpa es hoy es la primera vez que hago esto, el ejercicio es bastante largo esta es la parte que me esta fallando.

Comment: @alejandra Pero supongo yo que es uno de entre varios ejercicios (divididos), en ese caso deberas colocar solo el codigo de ese ejercicio en especifico que no logras implementar bien.

Comment: El metodo getPromedioEdad esta dentro de la clase persona. Ese es el código del ejercicio que no puedo resolver, los otros no los copie

Comment: "me tira este error: × should get age average with getPromedioEdad (6ms)", "should get age average with getPromedioEdad", si de verdad te tira esos errores tal cual entonces son errores personalizados, por lo cual asumo que aun no haz colocado tu codigo entero, como ha dicho el usuario @BetaM es muy complicado ayudarte sin conocer el codigo minimo pero necesario, en tu caso falta informacion importante del codigo, por ejemplo el como intentas instanciar una persona.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no tiene sentido meter la definición de una clase dentro de una función, para eso existe precisamente `new`.

En este ejemplo te muestro un método `calcularEdadPromedio()` que es parte de la clase `Persona` y que calcularía el promedio de edad de los amigos de esa persona.

### Código:

```js
/*
  LA CLASE
*/
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
    this.amigos = amigos;
  }

   calcularEdadPromedio() {
       /*
          Aquí se usa reduce para calcular el promedio
          Pero si prefieres puedes usar otro método basado en bucles
          o lo que desees. 
          El método usa la propiedad amigos del objeto Persona
          Dado que hablamos de una clase, convendría poner validaciones
          p.e. contolar que amigos no sea un objeto vacío
       */
       return (this.amigos.reduce((a, {edad}) => (a + edad), 0))/this.amigos.length;
  }

}


/* 
    CONTEXTO DE USO
    Creamos un objeto amigos 
*/

var amigos = [{
    nombre: 'Toni',
    edad: 33,
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Emi',
    edad: 25,
  }
];

/* Creamos instancia de la clase con new */
var mPerson = new Persona('Ale', 20, 'Javascript', amigos);

/* Usamos esa instancia para pedir el promedio */
console.log(`El promedio de los amigos de ${mPerson.nombre} es: ${mPerson.calcularEdadPromedio()}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

El método reduce es aplicable solamente a prototipos iterables, es decir, arreglos.

El error tiene sentido ya que estás intentando implementar el método en una variable numérica.

Mi sugerencia es que apuntes el mismo método al array, así:

```
const promedio = amigos.reduce((acumulador, amigo) => acumulador + amigo.edad))/ amigos.length
```

¡Espero te sirva!